# Can i execute query and sql function in same statement?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have a PreparedStatement and CallableStatement:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO parcels (cadastr,the_geom,status_id) VALUES(?,PolygonFromText(?, 4326),?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = ce.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, ts.getPackage().getSpecifyParcels().getExistParcel()
        .get(0).getCadastralNumber());
stmt.setString(2, WKT);
// stmt.setString(3, deleted);
stmt.setInt(3, status_id);
stmt.execute();
stmt.close();

java.sql.CallableStatement proc1 = ce
        .prepareCall("{call insert_into_wgs()}");
proc1.execute();
proc1.close();
```

Its possible to execute this query and function `insert_into_wgs()` in one statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the RETURNING keyword!

```
INSERT INTO parcels (cadastr,the_geom,status_id) 
VALUES (?, PolygonFromText(?, 4326), ?)
RETURNING insert_into_wgs()
```

Comment: Thank for answer. But unfortunately `insert_into_wgs() ` works with results of INSERT query(

Comment: Why you use SELECT instead VALUES?

Comment: Replaced my previous answer with a real solution

Comment: Because I copied it from rs.'s solution ;) His post is already deleted btw. Fixed.

Comment: So i gonna use this: `INSERT INTO parcels (cadastr,the_geom,status_id) VALUES( ?,PolygonFromText(?, 4326),? )RETURNING insert_into_wgs()` ????